How to coat a CF nylon part to avoid release of fibers?
I am printing a mostly flat speaker grille to avoid the cone dome to be touched and ruined, and I'm using Fiberon PA612-CF15 because of its high bending strength and stiffness.
Once printed, I would like to coat it to avoid fibers be released when inevitably someone will try to play with it. As I recently learned, releasing fibers is quite likely:



Which coatings can I use for the purpose? it should stick well to PA612, be transparent and tolerate some bending without cracking/detaching if someone pushes the grille in the center to bend it inwards.
